# Is it possible to extract Map keys as type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript you can do

```js
const obj = {
  '123-123': 1,
  '456-456': 2,
}

type objKeys = keyof typeof obj
```

And `objKeys` is a union type `'123-123' | '456-456'`.

Is something similar possible if `obj` was not an object, but a Map?

```js
const map = new Map<string, number>([
  ['123-123', 1],
  ['456-456', 2],
])

type mapKeys = ???
```

Comment: Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr573w) help you? It introduces another variable but otherwise it should not be possible to extract any more type information out of a `Map`

Comment: Part of the point of a `Map` is to accept arbitrary keys of the given key type.  So `map.set("789-789", 3)` is fine, so what do you want `mapKeys` to be other than `string`?  In your `obj` example the compiler won't let you add random extra keys, unless you gave it the type of `{[k: string]: number}` and then again `objKeys` would be `string`.  It kind of feels like you want conflicting things... which one do you *actually* want?  Known keys, or the ability to set arbitrary keys?  And if it's "known keys", what is the advantage of a `Map` for you?

Comment: @TobiasS. That's super helpful, thanks! But why does it work? I don't understand the `typeof mapContent[number][0]` part.

Comment: @jcalz I don't have any advantage compared to an object, the map will be constant anyway.

Comment: If the map will be constant then you probably want to use a value of the `ReadonlyMap` type instead of `Map`... you could make a helper function to produce a string-keyed readonly map, from which the keys will be a known union, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9EKVN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that's great, it has everything I need!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write `new Map<string, number>(...)` then you are explicitly giving the `Map` a `string` key type, which means it will allow you to `set()` and `get()` and string-valued key.  If you want to constrain the keys to a particular [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) then you will need to change how you construct the `Map`.  For example, if you define `MapKeys` ahead of time, you can use it instead of `string`:

```
type MapKeys = '123-123' | '456-456';
const map = new Map<MapKeys, number>([
  ['123-123', 1],
  ['456-456', 2],
]);
```

But this is a bit redundant, and backwards from what you're asking for anyway.  You want the compiler to *infer* `MapKeys` from the arguments passed to the `Map` constructor.

---

Since you said that the use case is for the `Map` to be constant (so not only are its keys constrained, but its values also do not change), then you might be better served by [the `ReadonlyMap<K, V>` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a2b785b6cbfc045edf6e092249fbbccb4d5439d7/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L38-L43) provided by TypeScript.  There is no `ReadonlyMap` at runtime, but the TypeScript compiler will allow you to assign a `Map` instance to a variable of type `ReadonlyMap`.

And if we want the compiler to infer `MapKeys`, we might want to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the constructor's key type to `string`, which gives the compiler a hint that strings.

Both of these imply that a helper function to create new `ReadonlyMap<K, V>` where `K` is constrained to `string` will help:

```
function ReadonlyMapWithStringKeys<K extends string, V>(
  iterable: Iterable<[K, V]>): ReadonlyMap<K, V> {
  return new Map(iterable)
}

const map = ReadonlyMapWithStringKeys([
  ['123-123', 1],
  ['456-456', 2],
])
// const map: ReadonlyMap<"123-123" | "456-456", number>
```

Now we can see that `map` is of a type whose keys are strongly typed.  We can now define `MapKeys` from it.  There are multiple ways to do it; one is using [conditional type inference with the `infer` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)

```
type MapKeys = typeof map extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, any> ? K : never;
// type MapKeys = "123-123" | "456-456"
```

Or you could use utility types like [the `Parameters<T>` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to ask the compiler what the first parameter of `map.get()` is:

```
type MapKeys = Parameters<typeof map["get"]>[0]
// type MapKeys = "123-123" | "456-456"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript inferrence with conditional types. Full docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)

```
const map = new Map([
  ['123-123', 1] as const,
  ['456-456', 2] as const,
])

type MapKey<T extends Map<any, any>> = T extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never

type MyMapKey = MapKey<typeof map>
```

**Bonus:** If you mark your map entries with as const, the extracted type is inferred to const values.

Check [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wLwzAUwO4wLLIAUA2gLABQMMxA5AIwBMAzALSNM0A0MdAujAggxQkKJwpVaAFgCsANhay5XGA36Dh4aOPK8AlBQpQAnkkz5kAaUzGAPABUYmAB5RMYACZCCSWwjDG3P7GAHwhaDCOLm6e3si2AJZgAGaYAE4wlkEB4QD8mTAAXBiYAG7pRqbmPgBqCAA2AK6YDk6u7l4WvsHZoeHoUe2xXX4B3EmpGTV5MDVFJeVphuQmZvjGPtbGEZs2tquYIMnwyCGVa3gbyHVN5ui1Dc37VUcnSGfkFEA).